# search tags in a php string with strpos

Tags: php, strpos

this is an UTF-8 string

```
$string = '<h2> a none english char - utf-8 string </h2>';
```

I want to check `<h2>` tag exist in $string or not

I try:

```
if(strpos($string , '<h2>'))
or
if(strpos($string , '<h2>') == true )
or
if(strpos($string , '<h2>') === true)
or
if(mb_strpos($string , '<h2>' ))
```

but all of these condition retrun false. whats the wrong?

Comment: Did you tried: [`mb_strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) ?

Comment: strpos returns an int or boolean false, therefore `=== true` will ALWAYS fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests fail because your "needle" string occurs right at the start of your haystack, therefore strpos() will return `0`, to indicate start-of-string.

```
if (0)          -> false
if (0 == true)  -> false
if (0 === true) -> false
```

You cannot use equality in this case, you must use inequality:

```
if (strpos(...) !== FALSE)
```

comment followup:

I fail to see how it could "no effect at all":

```
php > $string = '<h2> a none english char - utf-8 string </h2>';
php > var_dump(strpos($string, '<h2>'));
int(0)
php > var_dump(strpos($string, '<h2>') == true);
bool(false)
php > var_dump(strpos($string, '<h2>') === true);
bool(false)
php > var_dump(mb_strpos($string, '<h2>'));
int(0)
php > var_dump(mb_strpos($string, '<h2>') !== false);
bool(true)
```

Comment: we are taking about putting it all in condition puirly. not using `var_dump`.

Comment: yes, and? var_dump is for debugging, to see the result of the condition. and as you can see by my example edit, it shows EXACTLY what I was saying. your condition produces boolean false, because you're doing incorrect comparisons, while my `!== false` produces a boolean true, exactly as it should.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh You can put any condition in a var_dump() and see the result of the condition. Marc B's answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks. now it works. Could I use !== for other in general? dose it always return me correct answer?

Comment: yes that's great, i know that , but what he need to do in last. that will be mentioned. he cannot leave his code like you suggested. sorry for my words. my intension is not to heart you.

Answer (score 0):

Your last one should work (using [mb_strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php)).
But in your string, "" is right the beginning of the string, and therfore is in position 0.
mb_strpos or strpos returns the position of the sub-string if found, or boolean false if not found.
since you are checking the condition like this:

```
if (mb_strpos($string, '<h2>'))
```

You are actually checking:

```
if (0)
```

And that why you see it as false.
Use:

```
if (mb_strpos($string , '<h2>') !== false)
```